# Connection to Python debugger failed socket closed in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, debugging, console, pydev

[image]Hi all!  I want to set it up the same way as the teacher, but so far unsuccessfully .. an error crashes. Is it really possible to set it up like this on PyCharm Community?

[image]I am attaching a fragment from the course on udemy.        how to set also?

Comment: What is the error ? Very strange to name `runserver` but set `python manage.py shell` in env options. What you want to do is unclear: You want to run the django server in debug ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.